# How do I prevent mass emailing on my website? (web directory)

Tags: recaptcha, contact-form, spam-prevention

I'm getting a web directory developed in Node.js. The directory will contain profile pages of a few hundreds people. There will be a contact form on each profile page to contact the individuals.
What can I do to prevent spammers to go on each profile page one by one and contact the directory members with unsolicited messages? (not sure Google recaptcha would catch that if the messages look legit and are posted by real humans)
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Google recaptcha is used only to prevent bots to send message.
In your case it will not be the good solution I think.

I would allow someone to be able to contact **only if they have an account and/or if they validate their email**.

In my experience when you ask to **confirm their email**, the spammers will not do.

Comment: Thanks @David. Visitors won't have the possibility to create accounts, and asking them to validate their email is not ideal as it requires an extra step that I want to avoid. Do you think that setting up a rule so that someone with the same IP address cannot send more than X emails per hour via the contact forms would work? (not even sure if this is technically feasible). Tks

Comment: I understand you point. It is true validating the email has a cost...

Comment: Your idea is good, it depends the system you use, but yeah you can save in the cache of your app the IP and block it after a number of sending. Sounds good.